# ModelForm with overrides throwing ValueError

Tags: django

I've basically got something like this,

**the model**

```
class Survey(models.Model):
    aggbs_0 = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(verbose_name='Has Tantrums.', blank=True)
```

**the form**

```
class SurveyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    nsf_CHOICES = (
        (1, 'Never',), 
        (2, '',),
        (3, 'Sometimes',),
        (4, '',),
        (5, 'Frequently',),
    ) 
    aggbs_0 = forms.ChoiceField(required=False, widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizRadioRenderer), choices=nsf_CHOICES, label=Survey._meta.get_field_by_name('aggbs_0')[0].verbose_name)
    class Meta:
        model = Survey
```

**the view**

```
def survey_create(request):
    form = SurveyForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        saved = form.save(commit=False)
        saved.save()
        messages.success(request, "submitted.")
    return render_to_response("reports/survey_form.html", 
                            locals(),
                            context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And when I submit my form without filling out a radio button I am getting,

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

I want the value to be 0 if they don't fill out a radio button.

Comment: What value do you want it to have when the user doesn't select a button?

Comment: I would be delighted if it would save a zero. I have tried overriding the save function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation of [ChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield) states:

> - Empty value: `''` (an empty string)
> - Normalizes to: A Unicode object.

In fact, *invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''* is the result of calling `int` on an empty string.

What you want to use is a [TypedChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#typedchoicefield):

> - Empty value: Whatever you’ve given as `empty_value`
> - Normalizes to: A value of the type provided by the `coerce` argument.

In your case, you should use *TypedChoiceField* the same way you were using *ChoiceField*, except that you should also add the `empty_value=0` parameter.